# Serial does not read buffer with integer characters greater than 43

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, serial-data, integer

I'm trying to write a script to move an object coupled to a linear axis through a `stepper motor`. The user must send information such as the `length` to be moved, the `speed` of movement, the `direction` of movement, or even if he wants to make millimetric adjustments via the `serial`. However, `I can't read lengths from 43 mm` where I `send` the `integer 43 over serial`. I tested several methods that I found on the internet. Below is the current code and some alternatives of the serial read section that failed.

```
void(* resetFunc) (void) = 0;

//Serial read
const int bufferSize = 30; // Tamanho máximo para o buffer de leitura
char buffer[bufferSize];   // Buffer para armazenar os dados lidos via serial

//Step motor
const int stepPin = 3;
const int senPin = 2;
const int enPin = 8;
int sen, sp, len, ad; //sen = forward or backward, sp = speed, len = length, ad = enable steps to adjustment
int REV;//motor revolutions
int time_motor; // interval of pulse (on/off)

void setup()

{
  
  pinMode(stepPin,OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(senPin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enPin,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(enPin,LOW);
  
  Serial.begin(9600);
 
  while (!Serial.available()) {
    delay(10);
  }

  int bytesRead = Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', buffer, bufferSize);

  buffer[bytesRead] = '\0';

  sscanf(buffer, "%d,%d,%d,%d", &ad, &sen, &len, &sp);

  Serial.print("ad: ");
  Serial.println(ad);
  Serial.print("sen: ");
  Serial.println(sen);
  Serial.print("len: ");
  Serial.println(len);
  Serial.print("sp: ");
  Serial.println(sp);
      
  time_motor = 100;
        
  REV = int(768 * len);
  
  if(ad == 0){   
    if (sen == 1){
      backward(REV, time_motor);
      }
  
    else {
      forward(REV, time_motor);
      }
  
      resetFunc();
  }
  else{
    if(sen == 1){backward(768, time_motor);resetFunc();}
    else{forward(768, time_motor);resetFunc();}
  }
}

void forward(int len_fact, int time_c) {
  digitalWrite(enPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(senPin, HIGH);
  for (int x = 0; x < len_fact; x++) {
    digitalWrite(stepPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(time_c);
    digitalWrite(stepPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(time_c);
  }
}

void backward(int len_fact, int time_c) {
  digitalWrite(enPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(senPin, LOW);
  for (int x = 0; x < len_fact; x++) {
    digitalWrite(stepPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(time_c);
    digitalWrite(stepPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(time_c);
  }
}


void loop()
{

}
```

An alternative below:

```
  while (!Serial.available()) {
    // Aguarda até que haja dados disponíveis na porta serial
  }

  delay(100); // Pequeno atraso para garantir que todos os dados tenham chegado

  int bytesRead = 0;
  while (Serial.available() && bytesRead < bufferSize - 1) {
    char c = Serial.read();
    if (c == '\n') {
      break; // Termina a leitura ao encontrar uma quebra de linha
    }
    buffer[bytesRead] = c;
    bytesRead++;
  }

  // Adiciona o caractere nulo para indicar o final da string
  buffer[bytesRead] = '\0';

  // Usa a função sscanf para extrair os números do buffer
  sscanf(buffer, "%d,%d,%d,%d", &ad, &dir, &len, &sp);

  // Imprime os valores lidos para verificá-los
  Serial.print("ad: ");
  Serial.println(ad);
  Serial.print("dir: ");
  Serial.println(dir);
  Serial.print("len: ");
  Serial.println(len);
  Serial.print("sp: ");
  Serial.println(sp);
```

And the other:

```
  while (!Serial.available()) {
    // Aguarda até que haja dados disponíveis na porta serial
  }

  // Lê os dados da porta serial e armazena no buffer até atingir o tamanho máximo
  int bytesRead = 0;
  while (bytesRead < bufferSize - 1) {
    if (Serial.available()) {
      char c = Serial.read();
      if (c == '\n') {
        break; // Termina a leitura ao encontrar uma quebra de linha
      }
      buffer[bytesRead] = c;
      bytesRead++;
    }
  }

  // Adiciona o caractere nulo para indicar o final da string
  buffer[bytesRead] = '\0';

  // Usa a função sscanf para extrair os números do buffer
  sscanf(buffer, "%d,%d,%d,%d", &ad, &dir, &len, &sp);

  // Imprime os valores lidos para verificá-los
  Serial.print("ad: ");
  Serial.println(ad);
  Serial.print("dir: ");
  Serial.println(dir);
  Serial.print("len: ");
  Serial.println(len);
  Serial.print("sp: ");
  Serial.println(sp);
```

Serial returns nothing or "?". How should I proceed to solve this problem?
I'm using an original Arduino uno and writing in the arduino IDE. The version is 1.8.19.

Comment: maybe you set the wrong baud rate in the serial console

Comment: reduce your program. to minimum code that still exhibits the problem

Comment: You are sending 4 numbers over serial, right? Please copy and paste the exact numbers that you are sending.

Comment: Before the `sscanf` I would be printing what is in that buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you didn't provided that much info, but i picked up on some of your code (below) and in the serial monitor i can read all the numbers :

```
    const int bufferSize = 30; // Tamanho máximo para o buffer de leitura
char buffer[bufferSize];   // Buffer para armazenar os dados lidos via serial

//Step motor
const int stepPin = 3;
const int senPin = 2;
const int enPin = 8;
int dir, sp, len, ad; //sen = forward or backward, sp = speed, len = length, ad = enable steps to adjustment
int REV;//motor revolutions
int time_motor; // interval of pulse (on/off)

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
while (!Serial.available()) {
    // Aguarda até que haja dados disponíveis na porta serial
  }

  delay(100); // Pequeno atraso para garantir que todos os dados tenham chegado

  int bytesRead = 0;
  while (Serial.available() && bytesRead < bufferSize - 1) {
    char c = Serial.read();
    if (c == '\n') {
      break; // Termina a leitura ao encontrar uma quebra de linha
    }
    buffer[bytesRead] = c;
    bytesRead++;
  }

  Serial.println(buffer);

  // Adiciona o caractere nulo para indicar o final da string
  buffer[bytesRead] = '\0';

  // Usa a função sscanf para extrair os números do buffer
  sscanf(buffer, "%d,%d,%d,%d", &ad, &dir, &len, &sp);

  // Imprime os valores lidos para verificá-los
  Serial.print("ad: ");
  Serial.println(ad);
  Serial.print("dir: ");
  Serial.println(dir);
  Serial.print("len: ");
  Serial.println(len);
  Serial.print("sp: ");
  Serial.println(sp);
}
```

[image]